# Import Amchart into PDF using TCPDF

Tags: php, tcpdf, amcharts, html-to-pdf

I am using the Amchart to display the column chart on my site.
Now I have to generate the pdf report from these HTML I am using TCPDF library.
The problem is how I can import the amchart into an image and put that image into the PDF at the same time.

When I click on the download pdf button it should import the chart as PNG and then this image will show in generated pdf these process should complete by clicking on download button.

Is there any solution?